# java.lang.VerifyError when using WCMUsePojo in a simple AEM application

Tags: java, maven, aem, verifyerror, maven-scr-plugin

Below is the error which I get when I do a `mvn clean install` of the project. It is a simple AEM application in AEM 6.1 where i am trying to use WCMUse.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr (gene
rate-scr-descriptor) on project myproject-bundle: Execution generate-scr-descrip
tor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr failed: An API incompati
bility was encountered while executing org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:s
cr: java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return

[ERROR] Exception Details:
[ERROR] Location:
[ERROR] com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUsePojo.<init>()V @1: return
[ERROR] Reason:
[ERROR] Error exists in the bytecode
[ERROR] Bytecode:
[ERROR] 0x0000000: 2ab1
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/org/apache/felix/maven-scr-plugin/1.7.4/ma
ven-scr-plugin-1.7.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.2/maven-
archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/ple
xus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-al
pha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr.gene
rator/1.1.4/org.apache.felix.scr.generator-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.
jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/D:/Maven_Repo/asm/asm-all/3.1/asm-all-3.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>my-group-id:myprojec
t-bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContaine
rException
```

Below is the code where i am using WCMUsePojo.

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.controllers;
import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;;
public class TestController extends WCMUsePojo{

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        testMethod();
    }

    void testMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("test method");
    }

}
```

If I remove extends WCMUsePojo there is no error and the build runs fine.

Please find below the pom which I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P A R E N T P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

    <artifactId>myproject-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>My Project Bundle</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.jcr.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <classifier>obfuscated-apis</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- B U I L D D E F I N I T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>my-group-id.myproject-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/apps/myproject/install</slingUrl>
                    <usePut>true</usePut>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>
                        *.impl
                    </excludePackageNames>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>auto-deploy</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Use the sling plugin to automatically deploy the bundle to the 
                        JCR tree -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-bundle</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <slingUrl>http://${cq.host}:${cq.port}</slingUrl>
                                    <slingUrlSuffix>/apps/myproject/install</slingUrlSuffix>
                                    <user>${cq.user}</user>
                                    <password>${cq.password}</password>
                                    <usePut>true</usePut>
                                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: try adding a constructor `public WCMUsePojo()`.

Comment: @VAr Tried. Same error while mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because of obfuscated uber-jar which provides only interfaces of the dependent classes, while WcmUsePojo is a class and not interface you see this issue. One way to resolve this is to either get unobfuscated jar for Adobe and use it, another is to explicitly add the sightly dependencies to your pom. You can check the version number and other details from your bundles console. In your case you would need only `com.adobe.cq.sightly.cq-wcm-sightly-extension` bundle as dependency in your POM

Comment: I could not find the sightly-extension jar in the adobe repository. Please find the error below :

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject-bundle: Could not resolve de
pendencies for project my-group-id:myproject-bundle:bundle:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could n
ot find artifact com.adobe.cq.sightly:cq-wcm-sightly-extension:jar:1.2.30 in ado
be (http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: updated the repository in pom to
`http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/adobe/aem/aem-api/6.0.0.1/` but still the same error